# Removing Specific End Values from a Column Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a year column in my data frame that has a few extra numbers attached to the end of the year. These only happen in the years 2011 and 1998. I have attached an example below of what it looks like after converting the column to a list to better see the data. I just need to remove the '-1' and '-9'. In the data it looks like 2011-1 and 1998-8. The reason I need to remove these is to merge it with another data frame that has the date formatted as 2011, 2012 for example.

[image: Link to example of what it looks like in Python]

Comment: are they perhaps a date _range_?

Comment: @ti7 It used to be a date range. I removed the last three numbers using strip but the years 2011 and 1998 had four numbers after the dash -

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have a df like below

```
df = DataFrame({
    'year':['2010', '2011-1', '1999', '1998-1']
})
```

Input df

```
    year
0   2010
1   2011-1
2   1999
3   1998-1
```

**Solution**

```
df['year'] = df.year.str.split('-').str[0]
```

**Output**

```
    year
0   2010
1   2011
2   1999
3   1998
```

**Explanation**
We are splitting the year column with '-' (if present) and then fetching the first part of the string in column.

Comment: For some reason, the solution that Utsav gave resulted in this error code.                  <ipython-input-161-9774cb9f8c29>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  perf1['Year'] = perf1.Year.str.split('-').str[0]"                                                                               Any tips? @Utsav

Comment: Can you please show what you are doing which results in warning. It does not make sense to me to create a deep copy and use resource. Below can be done if you want to apply changes on deep copy. --> df['year'] = df.year.copy().str.split('-').str[0]

Comment: I typed in the exact code that you wrote as the answer above and it gave me that warning. I am fairly new to pandas so I am unsure what you mean by deep copy.

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. I was creating a new dataframe variable to not interfere with the old one if I got it wrong. I just had to use the original alias from the initial dataframe and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a concept of shallow copy and deep copy which is how data is placed in memory locations while copying the data. You can search for deep and shallow copy.

Comment: Great! If you want to create a new df column you can use copy method --> df.year.copy().str.split('-').str[0]